# wso2 API Manager DataEndpoint Unable to send events to the endpoint

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using a combination of prepackaged wso2 identity server and wso2 api manager.
Recently configured a new environment .I installed custom domain names mylotsawso2dev.com and installed ssl.
Sometimes in the log , the below error is printed out.

```
[2017-05-15 02:47:42,525] ERROR - DataEndpoint Unable to send events to the endpoint.
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: Error while trying to publish events to data receiver :mylotsawso2dev.com/30.100.209.68:9612
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.send(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:81)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpoint$EventPublisher.publish(DataEndpoint.java:330)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpoint$EventPublisher.run(DataEndpoint.java:283)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.SessionTimeoutException: 6e9a4d58-3c3b-4e59-a7ff-060322cd7d76 expired
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryEventSender.processResponse(BinaryEventSender.java:164)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.send(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:76)
        ... 8 more
```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a harmless error printed when session timeout occurs in event publisher. Ideally, this should be an info log. [Public JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-1588) is open to track this issue.